# How to authenticate users from database with an authentication provider?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm a newbie with spring security and I want to authenticate users  with database.
I've created a login page and an authentication Provider  with jdbc that cheks if the user exists in the database.
But the problem that my code doesn't do that, it allows all users to log in!
what's wrong with my code? 
Thanks for your help.

```
@Component(value = "userService")
public class UserService implements AuthenticationProvider {

@Inject
@Named(value = "dataSource")
private DataSource dataSource;

ResultSet resultSet = null;
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
Connection connection = null;

name=auth.getName();    
    pwd=auth.getCredentials().toString();


public Authentication authenticate(Authentication auth)
        throws AuthenticationException {
    final String select_auth = "select username,password from users where username='"+name+"' and password='"+pwd+"'";
    try {
        connection = dataSource.getConnection();
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(select_auth);
        resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        while (resultSet.next()) {

                 //what to return here ?
            }
```

here is my security-confg.xml:

```
<http auto-config="true">
    <form-login login-page="/login" username-parameter="j_username"
        password-parameter="j_password" default-target-url="/accueil"

        authentication-failure-url="/403" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login" />
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider ref="userService">
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Comment: You will be better off using `UserDetailsService` instead of a full `AuthenticationProvider` implementation.  See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31691975/spring-security-authorization-not-authorizing-user) for the simplest possible of configuring a `UserDetailsService` for your use case.

Comment: thanks for your response @manish but the link you posted is not found.

Comment: The poster deleted the post and [re-posted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31715493/spring-security-not-authorizing-user) it.  Check the new post.  See the top of the post and the SQL query used for fetching username and password.

Answer (score 0):

In the code, I don't see the place to set username and password to the query. you try to get the name and password and check that your query returns any result

```
  @Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
    String select_auth = "select username,password from users where username=? and password=?";
    String username = authentication.getName();
    String password = (String) authentication.getCredentials();

    preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(select_auth);
    p.setString(1, username);
    p.setString(2, password);
    resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

    while (resultSet.next()) {

        List<SampleAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<SampleAuthority>();

        SampleAuthority a = new SampleAuthority();
        authorities.add(a);
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities1 = authorities;
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password, authorities1);

   }
}

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> arg0) {
    return true;
}

class SampleAuthority implements GrantedAuthority {

    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        return "ROLE_USER";
    }

}
```

in the configuration, you can add

```
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
<logout logout-url="/logout" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I didn't really understand where is the problem in putting the username and the password in the query .. But what I'm looking for is to get the username and password from a login page  and check if they exists in the database  via this Authentication provider ..

Comment: What I mean is can you check the ResultSet to make sure it does not always return value?! One more thing, can you pls share the spring-security.xml config?! Do you use the anonymous role in the intercept?!

Comment: I've checked it ! the resultSet doesn't return any value from the database ! What's the problem with it ? I've updated the post with the spring-security.xml

Comment: I've updated the authentication provider and added a login check.. but still confused what to return ?

Comment: There are two things you have to check: the resultSet from your DB query. Please double-check my code. Then check if the DB returns any data in result set?! The second is the question "what should be returned?", pls see the sample code of GrantedAuthority.